# How do I call two functions inside an if statement that is inside a for loop in Java?

Tags: java, function

I am supposed to implement two functions that I already created (named isTargetWithinRange (what it does: given a target, this says whether a target is within range) and isTargetVisited (which checks that the target wasn't already captured)).

In this part, I am supposed to get the index of an unvisited target within the "range" (maximum distance to my target) of my current location. To do this, I am trying to create a for loop that contains an if-statement that calls my two variables.

The trouble that I am having is that I do not know how to call functions within the if-statement (that is within a for loop). I am trying to say within the if-statement that if isTargetWithinRange returns true or if isTargetVisited returns false, then the result is -1 (which in this case represents a target that is not yet captured).

```
            if (isTargetWithinRange(i) return true || isTargetVisited(i) return false)
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

I know that this question is probably incredibly confusing...but I really need help. I will try and clarify/define anything I can to get some help...

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the job

```
if (isTargetWithinRange(i) || !isTargetVisited(i)) {
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the method that returns true or false ( a predicate) from the action you want to take depending on the result. For example:

```
if(doIReturnTrue()) { // if true do something } .
```

The if statement will receive the result from the function, so you don't need

```
isTargetWithinRange(i) return true
```

Instead just pass the result of the method return into the if statement

```
if(isTargetWithinRange(i)){ // do if true etc }
```

To test a false result negate the return value using the logical not ! operator

```
if(!isTargetVisited(i)){ // do if true  }
```

In the above when isTargetVisited returns false apply the 'logical not' to change this to true

Answer (score -1):

I see that you might be new in Java. A function will return a value, in your case it is probably a boolean. Therefore you can use the following to achieve your result:

```
if (isTargetWithinRange(i) == true || isTargetVisited(i) == false) {
   return -1;
}
```

Since the function will return a value, the == will check if the returned value is equal to what you want it to be.

Comment: It is usually considered bad form to compare boolean values to "true" or "false"- too easy to mistype and omit one of the = signs.. Just use  `if (x)` or `if ( !x )`

Comment: @FredK the reason I formulated my answer that way is so the user can understand it better. If someone is new to java it is not so easy to understand if(x) if(!x) :)